# How to use the_permalink(); wordpress in select database query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I store my WordPress article links in custom table(not guid).

**Database**: Wordpress

**Table**: wp_custom_link

**column**: link_id, link

Now I want to show the id of the current WordPress article URL from my custom table. To do this I try following code:

---

```
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_custom_link WHERE link= '.the_permalink().'");

    foreach($result as $row)
       {   
          echo $row->link_id;
       }
```

---

Its not showing any output, but when I try using *WHERE link_id = 1* and try to display link, its work. Please Help me!

Thank You...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concatenation is incorrect. You should concatenate it like this:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_custom_link WHERE link= '".get_permalink()."'");
```

Note that I am using `get_permalink()`, using `the_permalink()` echo's the result, which in your case causes another error.

Even better, use the `$wpdb->prepare` method with a placeholder:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM wp_custom_link WHERE link= '%s'", 
        get_permalink()
    )
);
```